# DataContext overrides assigned public variable

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, datacontext

I am currently working with .NET 6 WPF and got some strange behaviour using custom classes and assigning as DataContext.

My code looks like this:

```
public partial class EditImage : Window
{
    public bool closed = false;

    customclass defaultvalue = new customclass();
    public EditImage(customclass inputvalue)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // assign Datacontext
        this.DataContext = inputvalue;
        defaultvalue = inputvalue;
    }

    // checking CheckBox with Binding to Office variable and clicking save-button


    private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var editedvalue = this.DataContext as customclass;

        // If changes made in Window, something should be executed
        if ((defaultvalue.Office != editedvalue.Office)
        {
            // Never reaches this section, because defaultvalue contains always the same data as   
            // editedvalue
        }
    }
}
```

Whereas customclass and its child class expandedclass looks like this:

```
public partial class customclass 
{
   public int ID {get; set;} 
   
   public string Articlenumber {get, set;}

   public bool Office {get; set;}
}

internal class expandedclass : customclass
{
   public DateTime Created {get; set;}

   public bool Deprecated {get; set;} 
}
```

As described in the first code section, I never reach the lines inside the if-statement, because both variables contain the same values.
The input to the EditImage-class is of type expandedclass, not customclass. So even when I assign editedvalue as customclass, it is always of type expandedclass...

What can I do to assign the input to EditImage to a variable, which will not be changed through user input inside the Window? So that I can compare the default input with the changed?

**What I tried:**
Changed the order of the assignments of the variables, set defaultvalue to static, set defaultvalue to readonly, cast all variables as customclass

**Edit:**
My working solution using AutoMapper now looks like this:

```
using AutoMapper;

customclass defaultvalue;
public EditImage(customclass inputvalue)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    defaultvalue = inputvalue;

    MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<customclass, customclass>());
    Mapper mapper = new Mapper(config);

    var changablevalue = new customclass();

    changablevalue = mapper.Map<customclass>(inputvalue);

    // assign Datacontext
    this.DataContext = changablevalue;

}
```

Comment: The variables `defaultvalue` and `editedvalue` are referencing the same object, i.e the same instance of customclass. Therefore the expression `defaultvalue.Office != editedvalue.Office` is always false.

Comment: You may keep the value of `defaultvalue.Office` in a boolean field and compare `editedvalue.Office` against that field.

Comment: @Clemens thanks for the advice. Have not thought of that!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set the `DataContext` to a separate instance of the `customclass`:

```
readonly customclass defaultvalue;
public EditImage(customclass inputvalue)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    defaultvalue = inputvalue
    DataContext = new customclass();
}
```

You will then be able to edit this instance in the view using the data bindings while `defaultvalue` stays unchanged.

Comment: And what about inputvalue? It is totally ignored now. You should certainly keep the assignment `defaultvalue = inputvalue;`  and assign `new customclass()` only to the DataContext, but also copy the property values from inputvalue to the new object in the DataContext.

Comment: @Clemens I used AutoMapper to solve copying the values from `inputvalue` to the `new customclass()` and assigned `defaultvalue = inputvalue;`, that worked for me.

Comment: AutoMapper seems total overkill when you could simpy write `new customclass { ID = inputvalue.ID, Articlenumber = inputvalue.Articlenumber, Office = inputvalue.Office }`. All this is very basic C# or OOP in general.

Comment: I updated the answer with an example of you could use the `inpuvalue` as the default.

Comment: @Clemens customclass contains many more elements, which I didn't mention here, because they are not relevant. But yes, for this few properties it's overkill.